# Execute jQuery function after another function completes

Tags: jquery, function

I want to execute a custom jQuery function after another custom function completes
The first function is used for creating a "typewriting" effect

```
function Typer()
{
    var srcText = 'EXAMPLE ';
    var i = 0;
    var result = srcText[i];
    setInterval(function() {
        if(i == srcText.length) {
            clearInterval(this);
            return;
        };
        i++;
        result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
        $("#message").html( result);
    },
    100);

}
```

and the second function plays a sound

```
function playBGM()
{
    document.getElementById('bgm').play();
}
```

I am calling the functions one after the another like

```
Typer();
playBGM();
```

But the sound starts playing as the text is getting typed.
I want to play the sound only AFTER the typewriting has finished.

Here is what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/GkUEN/5/

How can I fix this?

Comment: What if at the end of `function Typer()`, after `100);` insert `playBGM();` ? Here example http://jsfiddle.net/GkUEN/99/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use a callback parameter:

```
function Typer(callback)
{
    var srcText = 'EXAMPLE ';
    var i = 0;
    var result = srcText[i];
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(i == srcText.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
            return;
        }
        i++;
        result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
        $("#message").html(result);
    },
    100);
    return true;


}

function playBGM () {
    alert("Play BGM function");
    $('#bgm').get(0).play();
}

Typer(function () {
    playBGM();
});

// or one-liner: Typer(playBGM);
```

So, you pass a function as parameter (`callback`) that will be called in that `if` before `return`.

Also, [this](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) is a good article about callbacks.

```js
function Typer(callback)
{
    var srcText = 'EXAMPLE ';
    var i = 0;
    var result = srcText[i];
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(i == srcText.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
            return;
        }
        i++;
        result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
        $("#message").html(result);
    },
    100);
    return true;
        
    
}

function playBGM () {
    alert("Play BGM function");
    $('#bgm').get(0).play();
}

Typer(function () {
    playBGM();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">
</div>
<audio id="bgm" src="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/9/10780_1381246351.mp3">
</audio>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GkUEN/14/)

Comment: Or simply `Typer(playBGM);`

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, exactly, because `playBGM` is a function.

Comment: @Riturajratan There is a replace problem, not a callback problem. I replied assuming that the code is correct.

Answer (score 79):

You can use below code

```
$.when( Typer() ).done(function() {
       playBGM();
});
```

Comment: How can I combine multiple functions?
e.g.
when 1 done start 2
when 2 done start 3

Comment: This answer is not complete, it won't work on its own. A deferred object needs defining in the Typer function, and any other function in the chain,  along with resolving, and returning the promise. Only then will the sound play after the typer function completes. @SchweizerSchoggi  to  combine multiple functions:  `Typer().then(playBGM).then(ThirdFunction).then(yetAnotherFunction);` Make sure you're using JQuery 3.2.1 as this will NOT work with Jquery 1.71 as I just wasted 15 minutes on JSFiddle discovering.

Comment: Why this code is not working for me? Am I missing any library or something?! :/

Comment: how to pass arguments from first function to second function

Answer (score 4):

You could also use custom events:

```
function Typer() {
    // Some stuff

    $(anyDomElement).trigger("myCustomEvent");
}


$(anyDomElement).on("myCustomEvent", function() {
    // Some other stuff
});
```

Comment: nice idea, but you should write your code more related to the question

Answer (score 3):

Deferred promises are a nice way to chain together function execution neatly and easily. Whether AJAX or normal functions, they offer greater flexibility than  callbacks, and I've found easier to grasp.

```
function Typer()
{
var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var srcText = 'EXAMPLE ';
    var i = 0;
    var result = srcText[i];
```

**UPDATE :**

```
////////////////////////////////

  var timer=    setInterval(function() {
                    if(i == srcText.length) {

    // clearInterval(this);


       clearInterval(timer);

////////////////////////////////


   dfd.resolve();
                        };
                        i++;
                        result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
                        $("#message").html( result);
                },
                100);
              return dfd.promise();
            }
```

I've modified the play function so it returns a promise when the audio finishes playing, which might be useful to some. The third function fires when sound finishes playing.

```
   function playBGM()
    {
      var playsound = $.Deferred();
      $('#bgm')[0].play();
      $("#bgm").on("ended", function() {
         playsound.resolve();
      });
        return playsound.promise();
    }


    function thirdFunction() {
        alert('third function');
    }
```

Now call the whole thing with the following: (be sure to use Jquery 1.9.1 or above as I found that 1.7.2 executes all the functions at once, rather than waiting for each to resolve.)

```
Typer().then(playBGM).then(thirdFunction);
```

Before today, I had no luck using deferred promises in this way, and finally have grasped it. Precisely timed, chained interface events occurring exactly when we want them to, including async events, has never been easy. For me at least, I now have it under control thanks largely to others asking questions here.

Comment: "THIS" keyword is invalid here in clearInterval(this)

Comment: sqlchild, okay I didn't know I just took that part from the OP's function. It still works though, I ran it before posting and it didn't throw any errors. But if you say it's invalid I won't argue!