# Run one function after another: callback issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why function `lazy_2` doesn't run this way:

```
function lazy_1 (callback) {
    alert('lazy_1');
}

function lazy_2 () {
    alert('lazy_2');   
}

lazy_1(lazy_2);
```

? (Via [Execute jquery function after another function completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674380/execute-jquery-function-after-another-function-completes).)

jQuery method works well:

```
function lazy_1 (callback) {
    alert('lazy_1');
}

function lazy_2 () {
    alert('lazy_2');   
}

$.when( lazy_1() ).done(function() {
    lazy_2();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LL69/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `lazy_1()` doesn't call it's callback - in fact nobody does.  It needs to look like this for the callback to get called:

```
function lazy_1 (callback) {
    alert('lazy_1');
    callback();
}

function lazy_2 () {
    alert('lazy_2');   
}

lazy_1(lazy_2);
```

---

Your second code block above is equivalent to:

```
lazy1();
lazy2();
```

because you're just asking jQuery `$.when()` to run one function and then another with no promises involved (all synchronous code).

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually call `callback`.

```
function lazy_1 (callback) {
    alert('lazy_1');
    callback();
}

function lazy_2 () {
    alert('lazy_2');   
}

lazy_1(lazy_2);
```