# Javascript execute function after other function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a function called save:

```
function save(callback){
    var ed=tinyMCE.get('body');
    var data=ed.getContent();
    $('#saving').show();
    $('#save_err').hide();
    $.post('/article/ajax/save',{title:$('#title').val(),body:data,token:token,aid:<?php echo $article_id; ?>},function(d){
        $('#saving').hide();
        if(d.suc==1){
            $('#saved').show();
            setTimeout(function(){$('#saved').hide()},2000);
        }else{
            $('#save_err').html(d.err).show();
        }
        return true;
   },"JSON");
};
```

When the element #preview is clicked, I would like save to execute, and a redirect to happen after the function completes.

```
$('body').on('click','#preview',function(){
    save(function(){
        window.open('/article/preview/<?php echo $article_id; ?>','_blank');
    });
});
```

I have used both the accepted answer and the highest rated answer from here, neither are working. The redirect occurs before the function completes. [Execute jquery function after another function completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674380/execute-jquery-function-after-another-function-completes)

What I have also tried:

```
$('body').on('click','#preview',function(){
    $.when(save()).done(function(){
        window.open('/article/preview/<?php echo $article_id; ?>','_blank');
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$.when` does only work on functions that return promises. (and is unnecessary then)

Comment: What exactly do you consider the "completion" of the `save` function? When the ajax request loaded? when the `#saved` animation is done?

Comment: You created param callback, but didn't use it. Where does it must be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context of the following method

```
$('body').on('click','#preview',function(){
    save(function(){
        window.open('/article/preview/<?php echo $article_id; ?>','_blank');
    });
});
```

**You need to call the callback method** which you are passing as argument.

```
function save(callback){
    $.post(url,function(d){

        $('#saving').hide();
        if (d.suc == 1) {
            $('#saved').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#saved').hide();

                //CALL THE METHOD
                callback();  
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            $('#save_err').html(d.err).show();
        }
   },"JSON");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You never invoke callback function, so it never redirects. You need to call it when timeout is over:

```
function save(callback) {
    var ed = tinyMCE.get('body');
    var data = ed.getContent();
    $('#saving').show();
    $('#save_err').hide();
    $.post('/article/ajax/save', {
        title: $('#title').val(),
        body: data,
        token: token,
        aid: <? php echo $article_id; ?>
    }, function (d) {
        $('#saving').hide();
        if (d.suc == 1) {
            $('#saved').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#saved').hide();
                callback();  // <---- call callback
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            $('#save_err').html(d.err).show();
        }
    }, "JSON");
};
```