# how to run function after another one completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem to run function after another completes. I try callback like in this post but this dont work [Execute jquery function after another function completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674380/execute-jquery-function-after-another-function-completes) so maybe i do something wrong or my case is more complicated.

So I have function that run when I submit the form

```
$("#search-form").submit(ajaxSubmit(addSearchfuntion)); // addSearchfuntion is callback

function ajaxSubmit(callback) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var settings = {
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: $(this).attr("method")
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(result) {
        var $targetElement = $($form.data("ajax-target"));
        var $newContent = $(result);
        $($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);
        $newContent.effect("slide");
    });

    callback();

    return false;
};
```

After this when I get new form to my page i want to run another function that will handle this new form.

```
 function addSearchfuntion(){
     $('.Amount').change(updateQuantity);
 }
```

So how to solve this case?

Comment: @Rifky, Whats that

Comment: oops. pasted the wrong link.. check this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606021/javascript-execute-function-after-other-function-completes?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use anonymous function to bind the `submit` event handler. As of now you are executing the `ajaxSubmit()` method and binding its return value i.e. `false` as event handler.

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(){
    ajaxSubmit.bind(this)(addSearchfuntion);
});
```

And, invoke the `callback` method in the `done()` callback method of `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(result) {
    // Your existing code
    ....
    ....
    // call the callback
    callback();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You where pretty close, you need to place the callback call inside the method that is asynchronous

```
function ajaxSubmit(callback) {
    // this will be executed linear
    var $form = $(this);
    var settings = {
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: $(this).attr("method")
    };

    // this will be executed async
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(result) {

        // anything in here must be handled async, hence put your callback here

        var $targetElement = $($form.data("ajax-target"));
        var $newContent = $(result);
        $($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);
        $newContent.effect("slide");

        // call the callback
        callback();
    });

    // this will be executed linear and most likely before the async method
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply return function in `ajaxSubmit`:

```
function ajaxSubmit(callback) {
  return function(){
  var $form = $(this);
  var settings = {
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    type: $(this).attr("method")
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(result) {
    var $targetElement = $($form.data("ajax-target"));
    var $newContent = $(result);
    $($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);
    $newContent.effect("slide");
  });

  callback();

  return false;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your `callback` execution in your `ajax(settings).done` section. It'd look like this:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(result) {
    var $targetElement = $($form.data("ajax-target"));
    var $newContent = $(result);
    $($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);
    $newContent.effect("slide");

    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
});
```

You should also check to make sure `callback` exists before calling it, which is the thinking behind the `if (typeof callback)...` check. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042154/3856675) for more information.