# wait for function complete and do other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I wait for complete execution of a function and then call another function like

```
<script src="whereMyfunctionIs.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).ready(start());
    function start (){
        myfunction().WhenFunctionDone(myOtherFunction());
    }
</script>
```

I wanna know if there is a method(js or jQuery) that can wait til `myfunction` completes, I've already used done, ready and load, an it doesn't wait.

Error messages:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined
>
> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
>
> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Comment: Partially depends on what `myfunction()` does. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(window).ready(start());

function start (){
    $.when(myfunction()).done(myOtherFunction);
}
</script>
```

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is the documentation for `$.when`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous) is an explanation of Javascript's *synchronous* vs *asynchronous* execution.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674380/execute-jquery-function-after-another-function-completes) is a similar question to yours.