# Change the outerHeight of the #new-quote element after the getQuote() function was finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use a jQuery callback argument in the `getQuote()` function but it doesn't seem to work. Let me explain everything.

See the Pen [rpjXbO](https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/rpjXbO/) by Lukas ([@Kestis500](https://codepen.io/Kestis500)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

---

Here is a small snippet of the `getQuote()` function:

```
var getQuote = function(callback) {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  $.getJSON(
    "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&post",
    function(e) {
      var quoteText = e[0].content,
          quoteAuthor = e[0].title;

      $(".quote-text").html(
        '<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + quoteText
      );
      $(".quote-author").html("- " + quoteAuthor);

      $("#tweet-quote").attr(
        "href",
        "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=" +
           encodeURIComponent('"' + quoteText + '" ' + quoteAuthor));

      $("#tumblr-quote").attr(
        "href",
        "https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?posttype=quote&tags=quotes,
          freecodecamp&caption=" +
          encodeURIComponent(quoteAuthor) +
          "&content=" +
          encodeURIComponent(quoteText) +
          "&canonicalUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Fbuttons&shareSource=
          tumblr_share_button"
      );
    }
  );

  //setTimeout(function(){ callback(); }, 2000);
    callback();
};
```

As written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19674400, I used a callback as a `getQuote()` function argument but it doesn't change the `#new-quote` outerHeight, which should be equal to the `.quote-container` outerHeight:

```
getQuote(function() {
  $("#new-quote").outerHeight($(".quote-container").outerHeight());
});
```

This is a photo showing what's happening when I run this code:
[image]

As you can see, 1 element's outerHeight isn't equal to the 2 element's outerHeight.

---

Now, If I change only one little detail in the `getQuote()` function:

Before:

```
//setTimeout(function(){ callback(); }, 2000);
callback();
```

After:

```
setTimeout(function(){ callback(); }, 2000);
//callback();
```

[image]
Yes, both elements' outerHeight is perfectly equal.

---

The problem is, I don't want to use `setTimeout()` function because in some cases (for example slow internet connection) page's load speed can take up to 2 seconds (as stated in this function), so I'd like to remove this line of code and use only `callback();`.

However, it doesn't work. What should I change so the `#new-quote` outerHeight is changed exactly after `getQuote()` function?

Using `console.log()` function instead of `outerHeight()` worked.

When the `getQuote()` function is finished, it should change the outerHeight of the `.quote-container` element but it changes only after about 1 second (if the internet connection is fast) and because of `setTimeout()`, it changes only after 2 seconds, regardless of the internet speed, so if the connection is slow, `#new-quote` outerHeight won't change (for example if the connection is very slow because it won't load in 2 seconds for sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `calback` needs to be called inside the `$.getJSON` callback

Here is an updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rxpbwy

and here is the gist of the change:

The callback does not wait for the ajax `getJSON` to finish, it runs before that. You will have to move your `callback()` inside the success callback of the `getJSON`

before

```
 $.getJSON(
    "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&post",
    function(e) {
      ...
    }
  );
  callback(); // the request may or may not be done, but most likely not.
```

after

```
 $.getJSON(
    "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&post",
    function(e) {
      ...
      callback(); // the request is done and successful
    }
  );
```

Comment: It really worked amazing! I was trying to figure it out about a week and finally Ahmen... Thank you very much!! :)))