# setInterval function not stopping but runs infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Please check this on : 
http://jsfiddle.net/wmaokqh3/

```
<div id="message">
</div>
<audio id="bgm" src="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/9/10780_1381246351.mp3">
</audio>

<div id="count">
</div>


function Typer() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var srcText = 'EXAMPLE';
  var i = -(1);
  var result = '';
  setInterval(function() {
      if (i == srcText.length) {
        clearInterval(this);
        dfd.resolve();
      };
      $("#count").append('<br>i =' + i + ' , ');
      i++;
      result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
      $("#message").html(result + '---' + i + ' , ');
    },
    1000);
  return dfd.promise();
}
function playBGM() {
  var playsound = $.Deferred();
  $('#bgm')[0].play();
  $("#bgm").on("ended", function() {
    playsound.resolve();
  });
  return playsound.promise();
}
function thirdFunction() {
  alert('third function');
}
Typer().then(playBGM).then(thirdFunction);
```

Comment: because `this` has nothing to do with the interval Id.....

Comment: @epascarello: so what shall I use to cease its action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you learned to do `clearInterval(this)` but that is not correct. The `this` has nothing to do with the current interval. You need to use the generated id for the interval to cancel it.

```
var myInterval = window.setInterval(  )
```

and in your code you need to use that id

```
clearInterval(myInterval)
```

Comment: Seems we both like `myInterval`

Comment: @epascarello : I learned using THIS from Red Rum's answer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674380/execute-jquery-function-after-another-function-completes

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the `setInterval` to a variable in order to clear it later:

```
var result = '';
const myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i == srcText.length) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Comment: is using const here better than var ??

Comment: In general, *always* use `const` when possible - it behaves more reasonably and predictably, and makes reading code easier. (Use `let` if you have to reassign)

Answer (score 1):

So there is nothing in coding `clearInterval(this)`
clearInterval function needs a variable in the paranthesis in order to give it a variable you should set the interval function into a variable which should be like this `var inter = window.setInterval(function() {}, 1000);`